# Geometry nodes - Extract objects within a collection instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

As far as I can tell, in Blender 3.1, it is not currently possible to extract objects from a child collection within another collection.

[image]

As in, if I put the `Import` collection into a `Collection Info` node, check `Separate Children`, there will be 2 instances, `BagA` and `BagB`, but I wouldn't be able to extract the individual objects from these 2 instances.

[image]

So far the best option I have found is to assign different materials and use `Material Selection`, but this is a per-face filter, not per-object; and we cannot use `Instance` mode for obvious reasons.

Is there a good workaround and efficient workaround for this case?

Comment: maybe have two GN modifiers, first one would flatten the list... just an idea